# Is there are a formula for this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n-2}+\dots+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}+1$

for example:
$\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{1}$

I tried I don't know enough maths to solve this. I have studied sum of series of common ratio but here there is no common ratio so I could not solve this.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac1n$?

Comment: These are known as the [Harmonic Numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html) and, sadly, there is no simple closed formula for them.

Comment: But there is a series that gives a very good approximation even for very small numbers $n$. For the exact value however, you need brute force.

Comment: @barakmanos Do you mean $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$? :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Hahaha... I guess so :)

Comment: For what it is worth, we normally write series from left to right: $1+1/2+1/3+\cdots + 1/n$. Nothing wrong writing them the other way, except that it is sometimes harder to see the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are called the [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), and there is not an easy formula for them. However, they come increasingly close to $\ln n + \gamma$, where $$\gamma\approx 0.57721\,56649\,01532\,86060\,65120\,90082\,40243\,10421\,59335\,93992\ldots$$
is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). The bad news is that this relationship is the *deinfition* of the constant, so there is no easy way to obtain it. But it will definitely give you an idea of say, the sum of the first $1000$ fractions, which is 
$$
H_{1000} = \frac{1}{1000} + \cdots + \frac11 \approx 7.48547\,08606
$$
The difference between this and $\ln 1000$ is
$$
H_{1000} - \ln 1000 \approx 0.57771\,55815 \approx \gamma + 0.00049\,99167
$$
so, say, $0.577 + \ln n$ will be reasonably close in most cases.

Comment: where can i find the proof of these statements?